# How to include Apache POI Libraries inside Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I want to read Excel data from my internal storage and display it inside my application. For that we need Apache POI libraries, how am i supposed to include it in my project. I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3. Also please tell me the link where i can find the required files for reading excel data

I've found similar answers in the net but none related to doing it in Android Studio. So how do i do it?

Comment: Do you not have access to search engines? https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android ... https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX

Comment: Funny.. If u have then explain me step by step

Comment: Check out the code. Run it. See how far you can get. Come back here with a specific error if it doesn't work. Asking for tutorials or libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow